# LPX-00607: Invalid reference: 'ends-with'

Tags: oracle

i am getting the below errpr :

ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00607: Invalid reference: 'ends-with'.
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
when i am trying to execute the below statement in oracle SQLDeveloper, can some one pls help me in fixing the below query.

select emp_id, Extract(emp_xml, '//node()[ancestor::item_content or ancestor::stimulus_reference][not(ancestor::rationale)][self::inline_variable]/preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][not(ends-with(., " ") or ends-with(., " ") or ends-with(., "—"))]').getStringVal() as info
from emp where  emp_id ='S348'

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `Extract()` function [is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions068.htm#SQLRF00640), and I think it only supports the XPath 1.0 specification. `ends-with` is part of the XPath 2.0 specification.

If you use `XMLQuery()` instead, it uses XQuery, which contains XPath 2. So I think this should work?

```
select XMLQuery(
  '//node()[ancestor::item_content or ancestor::stimulus_reference][not(ancestor::rationale)][self::inline_variable]/preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][not(ends-with(., " ") or ends-with(., " ") or ends-with(., "—"))]'
  PASSING emp_xml RETURNING CONTENT).getStringVal() as info
from emp where emp_id ='S348';
```